# R error: C stack usage too close to limit on small dataset

Tags: r

I have just done a clean install of R on Ubuntu 18.04, and it does not really work.

I can do stuff like make vectors and dataframes, and get summaries. I can also make a histogram with the hist command just fine. However, the plot command does not work.

The following code, which is very basic and should work just fine:

```
data(faithful)
plot(faithful$eruptions)
```

runs for about 30 seconds, before giving the following error:

```
Error: C stack usage  7970244 is too close to the limit
```

I have seen lots of posts of other people having the same error, but it seems to be because they are dealing with large datasets/lots of recursion or something like that, but I have this problem even with a dataset of just 3 values. R should definitely be able to handle this without me increasing the limit, and it should not take 30 seconds to run.

Does anybody know what the problem could be?

Edit:
Output of `ulimit -a`:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 28697
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 28697
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Version info:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15) -- "Someone to Lean On"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

This is plain R in the terminal, not through any IDE.

Edit 2:

I have discovered that it works just fine on other user accounts on the computer. I've also started getting other weird issues (after a reboot I have to login to a Gnome session, then log out before I can log into plasma, but other users don't have that problem, sometimes the terminal can't launch, lots of things are crashing, etc) so I think this has nothing to do with R and is much bigger. Unfortunately, it might be a hardware issue (this computer has had wacky issues before on other operating systems).

Comment: Can you post your ulimit settings, ie. the output of `ulimit -a`? What version of R is this? Are you running this in plain R, or in some IDE like RStudio?

Comment: Added that info to the post

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with the library used for displaying the graph. But I don't know enough to try debugging it. Maybe someone else would help. Anyway, can you try the same thing under RStudio? That might give us some clues.

Comment: Same problem in RStudio. And this problem persisted after I uninstalled everything and reinstalled it.